# Derivation for formula of entropy representation

Tags: thermodynamics

I have trouble deriving the formula for entropy. The entropy function is:
$$S(U,V,n_i)=\frac{1}{T}\cdot U +\frac{P}{T}\cdot V - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\mu_{i}}{T}n_i$$ I apply Euler's theorem but instead I get: $$S(U,V,n_i)=\frac{1}{T}\cdot U -\frac{P}{T}\cdot V + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\mu_{i}}{T}n_i$$ I have do the substitutions of $P,T$ through division of partial derivatives. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the definition of G in terms of U, P, V, S, and T?  What is the equation for G of a mixture in terms of the chemical potentials and numbers of moles of the various species?

Comment: @ChetMiller I forgot to mention that I am new to Thermodynamics. So I would like an analytical explanation. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Are you not able to answer my leading questions?  Which one?

Comment: @ChetMiller What is G?

Comment: G is the Gibbs free energy.  If you don't know what G is, how can you know what $\mu$ is in your equation?